# Dynamic maven artifactId

Tags: scala, maven, sbt, maven-3, pom.xml

Is it possible for a POM to declare (or at least publish) an `artifactId` containing system properties? I mean the artifactId of the actual project, not dependencies.

I am using maven to build a scala project and thus, to allow publishing the project for different scala versions, in the pom.xml I'd like to declare:

`<artifactId>myproject_${scalaBinaryVersion}</artifactId>`

however maven 3.3. complains

> [WARNING] 'artifactId' contains an expression but should be a constant

Since I'd like this project to be interoperable with sbt, what would be the best way to publish an artifact suffixed with the scala binary version?

Comment: what about using classifiers instead of changing the artifactId?

Comment: unfortunately classifiers won't work due to transitive dependencies being indistinguishable

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The *Maven way* of doing so would be to use [classifiers](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependencies). From official documentation an example matches exactly your case (for different Java versions, but you can replace Java with Scala):

> The classifier allows to distinguish artifacts that were built from the same POM but differ in their content. It is some optional and arbitrary string that - if present - is appended to the artifact name just after the version number.
>   As a motivation for this element, consider for example a project that offers an artifact targeting JRE 1.5 but at the same time also an artifact that still supports JRE 1.4. The first artifact could be equipped with the classifier jdk15 and the second one with jdk14 such that clients can choose which one to use.

You can configure your POM as following:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <classifier>${scalaBinaryVersion}</classifier>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Note: we are adding an additional execution of the Maven Jar Plugin, so the project would create two jars, the normal one + an additional one with the specified (dynamic) classifier.

Then Maven will automatically publish the classified jar together with the normal jar (since it will be automatically attached to the build). You can then import it as a further Maven dependency in another project specifying its classifier as part of the Maven GAV (GAVC in this case):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>your.group.id</groupId>
    <artifactId>your.constant.artifact.id</artifactId>
    <version>your.version</version>
    <classifier>your.dynamic.classifier</classifier>
</dependency>
```

---

If you want to only build the classified one and no standard (unused) jar, you can skip the creation of the normal jar as following:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-jar</id>
                    <phase>none</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>scala-version-jar</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <classifier>${scalaBinaryVersion}</classifier>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Note: we are simply overriding the default execution of the Jar Plugin and binding it to a non existing phase. Hence Maven will only generate the classified Jar. The Install Plugin will then only install the classified one.

---

**Update: how to have dynamic artifactId installed with dynamic dependencies**

If different transitive dependencies are required for different dynamic versions, then indeed classifiers are not suitable.
Dynamic artifactIds with dynamic dependencies (and hence dynamic transitive dependencies) can however be achieved. Here below is the approach I used (and successfully tested):

As preference, I isolated the dynamic behavior in a profile, but you can obviously move it back to the default build (or have the profile active by default).

First of all, let's define in our pom the dependencies requiring a dynamic version, hence via properties as following:

```
<properties>
    <scalaBinaryVersion>scalaversion</scalaBinaryVersion>
    <dependency.version>4.11</dependency.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${dependency.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Note: for the sake of an example, I'm using Junit as dependency in this case and not in `test` scope, because I want it as `compile` dependency (again, just for this example).

Then let's define a profile for our dynamic behavior:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>build-scala-version</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <finalName>${project.artifactId}_${scalaBinaryVersion}-${project.version}</finalName>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.7</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>copy-pom</id>
                            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${scalaBinaryVersion}</outputDirectory>
                                <resources>
                                    <resource>
                                        <directory>${basedir}</directory>
                                        <includes>
                                            <include>pom.xml</include>
                                        </includes>
                                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                                    </resource>
                                </resources>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>replacer</artifactId>
                    <version>1.5.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>replace-artifactid</id>
                            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>replace</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <file>target/${scalaBinaryVersion}/pom.xml</file>
                                <token>&lt;artifactId&gt;${project.artifactId}&lt;/artifactId&gt;</token>
                                <!-- Replace to -->
                                <value>&lt;artifactId&gt;${project.artifactId}_${scalaBinaryVersion}&lt;/artifactId&gt;</value>
                                <outputDir>target\${scalaBinaryVersion}\replacer</outputDir>
                                <outputFile>pom.xml</outputFile>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.2</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>default-install</id>
                            <configuration>
                                <skip>true</skip>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>install-scala-version</id>
                            <phase>install</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>install-file</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                                <artifactId>${project.artifactId}_${scalaBinaryVersion}</artifactId>
                                <version>${project.version}</version>
                                <packaging>${project.packaging}</packaging>
                                <file>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}_${scalaBinaryVersion}-${project.version}.jar</file>
                                <pomFile>${project.build.directory}/${scalaBinaryVersion}/replacer/pom.xml</pomFile>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Note, the profile is customizing and providing the following:

- Changing the final Jar name with a dynamic name, depending on the runtime (aka dynamic) value, to `${project.artifactId}_{scalaBinaryVersion}-${project.version}`
- Filtering the existing pom file via the Maven Resources Plugin and [copying](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/copy-resources-mojo.html) it to the directory `target\${scalaBinaryVersion}`. The copied pom will have the dependencies with the dynamic version because the Resources Plugin will replace them. However, it will not have the dynamic artifactId (yet).
- Finalizing the dynamic pom file. The Replacer plugin will replace the `artifactId` XML element with the dynamic value (working on the `target` folder, hence everything on temporarely files)
- Skipping the generation of the default installation
- Performing a custom `install-file` [installation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-file-mojo.html) with the dynamic pom file (the filtered, copied and replaced one, providing dynamic dependencies (and as such dynamic transitive dependencies) and a dynamic artifactId

Hence, performing the following maven invocation:

```
mvn clean install -Pbuild-scala-version -DscalaBinaryVersion=hello -Ddependency.version=4.4
```

Maven will effectively install a new artifact in the local cache for the dynamic artifactId, the dynamic dependency version and the dynamic pom.
Note: if the concerned dependency version(s) and the dynamic scala version is the same, then you can save up a parameter and make the invocation shorter and more consistent.

Comment: thanks for the answer, however using classifiers is not possible since there will be issues with transitive dependencies and sbt relies on the binary version being present in the artifactId

Comment: What kind of issues related to classifiers?

Comment: Assume following dependencies:
 - project_2.10 -> lib_2.10 -> onlyscala2.10 and
 - project_2.11 -> lib_2.11 -> onlyscala2.11
As far as I know, classifiers can't have different dependencies

Comment: @JakobOdersky indeed, you are right, transitive dependencies would be an issue in that case. I updated my answer at its bottom with a different approach: it works well on my local tests, I got dynamic artifactId with dynamic dependencies and transitive dependencies. It is a step-by-step approach, but the solution works well.

Comment: I have followed your second approach and while it works for `mvn install ...` I haven't figured out how to release the crossed-compiled libraries with maven-release-plugin. Any hints?

Comment: @jgonian by releasing you mean deploying to a Maven repository? in that case you need to configure the `maven-deploy-plugin` and its [deploy-file](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html) goal

Comment: Interesting solution, thanks! Is it correct though, that Maven will still display the warning  `'artifactId' contains an expression but should be a constant`? The solution just replaces the expressions in the target folder / generated artifacts, right?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using maven for that I will saggest using multi pom with [maven helper plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html) so the artifactId is constant in each module.

Answer (score 0):

We follow the properties (via profiles) based approach as suggested here: [scala-maven-plugin FAQ](https://github.com/davidB/scala-maven-plugin/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions)

```
<artifactId>something_${scala.compat.version}</artifactId>

<properties>
 <scala.compat.version>2.12</scala.compat.version>
</properties>
```

maven will still issue a warning (with good reason), but with the help of the [flatten-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/flatten-maven-plugin/index.html) we build/install poms that has the variables replaced.

Comment: We have moved to having a pom file for each scala compat version, which has a static artifactId (and configured the scala compiler plugin to find it's sources in a different folder)

Comment: Not Good: [WARNING] 'artifactId' contains an expression but should be a constant.